# How to reduce the array of objects into single array of required key?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am new to Javscript and ,
I have a response from the server like this,

```
[
    {
        "name": "jim",
        "color": "blue",
        "age": "22"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sam",
        "color": "blue",
        "age": "33"
    },
    ... 80 more.
]
```

There are 85 such objects in the responseArray,
How do I use reduce method to get a resultArray with all the ages in the array.
What I intend to make is an ageArray, as below:

```
const ageArray = [22,33,77 ... 88 more]
```

How to go about?

Comment: Why do you need the ageArray? It looks need you want to do some calculation later...If this is the case, you may need ```reduce()``` actually.

Comment: Using reduce(), you can try like this const ageArray  = a.reduce((x, y) => { x.push(y.age); return x;}, []);  console.log(ageArray );

Answer (score 0):

Use `.map`:

```
let ageArray = arr.map(a => a.age);
```